# LoadAccelerators for a specific resource language

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keyboard-shortcuts, accelerator

I want to call [LoadAccelerators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but for a specific language in the resources. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some reverse engineering and here's how to load it from memory for a specific LCID:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) // exact fit - no padding
struct ACCEL_MEM{
    BYTE fVirt;
    BYTE byteReserved;
    WORD wKey;
    WORD wCmd;
    WORD wReserved;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

HACCEL LoadAcceleratorsIndirectWithLCID(UINT nResourceID, LCID lcid)
{
    //Open accelerators table with the 'nResourceID'
    //'nResourceID' = Resource ID to use
    //'lcid' = LCID to load resources for, or NULL to use the one from current thread
    //RETURN:
    //      = HACCEL loaded -- must be removed with DestroyAcceleratorTable(), or
    //      = NULL if error
    ASSERT(nResourceID);

    HACCEL hAccel = NULL;

    HINSTANCE hInst = ::GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    if(hInst)
    {
        //Do we have a LCID?
        if(lcid == NULL)
            lcid = ::GetThreadLocale();

        //Get language ID
        LANGID langid = LANGIDFROMLCID(lcid);

        //Try to load for specified resource
        HRSRC hResource = ::FindResourceEx(hInst, RT_ACCELERATOR, MAKEINTRESOURCE(nResourceID), langid);
        if(hResource == NULL)
        {
            //If failed, use default lcid
            hResource = ::FindResource(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(nResourceID), RT_ACCELERATOR);
        }

        if(hResource)
        {
            HGLOBAL hglb = LoadResource(hInst, hResource);
            if(hglb)
            {
                LPVOID lpsz = LockResource(hglb);
                DWORD dwcbSz = ::SizeofResource(hInst, hResource);
                if(lpsz &&
                    dwcbSz)
                {
                    ACCEL_MEM* pMem = (ACCEL_MEM*)lpsz;

                    //Count items in the table
                    int nCnt = 0;
                    ACCEL_MEM* pTest = pMem;
                    for(;; pTest++)
                    {
                        nCnt++;
                        if(pTest->fVirt & 0x80)
                            break;
                    }

                    //Reserve mem
                    ACCEL* pAccels = new ACCEL[nCnt];

                    //Parse data
                    for(int i = 0; i < nCnt; i++)
                    {
                        pAccels[i].fVirt = pMem[i].fVirt & 0x7f;
                        pAccels[i].key = pMem[i].wKey;
                        pAccels[i].cmd = pMem[i].wCmd;
                    }

                    //Create accel table
                    hAccel = ::CreateAcceleratorTable(pAccels, nCnt);

                    //Free mem
                    delete[] pAccels;
                    pAccels = NULL;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return hAccel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You put your language-specific resources in a DLL. At run time, you load that DLL and specify the DLL's handle as the `hInstance` when you call `LoadAccelerators`.

Comment: OK. What if my resources are in the same .exe file that I'm calling LoadAccelerators from?

Comment: @c00000fd: I've never tried it, but each table needs a unique name, so you should be able to specify the name/number of the specific accelerator table you need (second parameter to LoadAccelerators).

Comment: Hmm. No, I don't think so. Each resource ID seems to be the same for all languages. From what I can tell I can load it using FindResourceEx but I'm not sure how to load it from memory. Any idea on that front?

Comment: @c00000fd: Sorry, but no, not a clue with that route.

Comment: Yeah, thanks anyway. Normally WinAPIs come in Load...Indirect flavor, but not this one.

Comment: @c00000fd: Yeah -- LoadAccelerators is *ancient* (Windows 1.0), from back when most of this sort of thing was still mostly theoretical.